# How to block/disable Snapchat's in-app web browser?

Tags: browser, snapchat

In snapchat, if you type into a chat a website URL you can then access snapchat's browser. For personal reasons, I've taken the time to remove my phones browser via rooting so that I can't access the web. However, I really enjoy snapchat and don't want to have the temptation of using the internet at any point via snapchat.

I can't find any settings to block it. The only way I can think of blocking websites is via the hosts file, but it only works for individual sites; I want to have no access whatsoever via the snapchat browser.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Bump. I really want an answer